# Roslyn Single File Generator Diagnostics

Tags: roslyn, diagnostics, file-generation

I am using Roslyn for creating Single File Generators. Under certain conditions I'd like to report an error. I am using IVsGeneratorProgress.GeneratorError function to add the error to the error list. However, I also want to have some code underscored with red line to indicate an error. How do I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for exactly. Is your goal to add errors to the error list?

Comment: I can add the error to the list by using GeneratorError function, but I would like also to underscore part of the code with red. This I do not know how to do.